# Make Thread usable if it waits for other stuff

Tags: java, threadpool

I have 10 objects which implement this method:

```
public CompletableFuture<TestObject> processAsync(Executor executor){
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        () -> DoLongSynchronousRestCall(), //Takes 3 Seconds
        executor
    );
}
```

I have implemented a little bit of code which iterates over all 10 Objects and checks if the completableFuture of the processAsync method isDone() and then extracts the result. This works totally fine and as expected.

Now comes the "tricky" thing. My Threadpool contains 5 Threads, this means I can work on 5 objects at the same time, which results in everything taking 6 Seconds.

But what I am trying to achieve is that the 5 Threads all execute DoLongSynchronousRestCall(), then they see they need to wait, and directly look for more work. Which means everything should be done in ~ 3.4 seconds (if we assume that the overhead of all this stuff is like 0.4 second).

Is something like that possible?

Like for example marking a Threadexecution as "please look in 1 second again, in the meantime you can do more work"?

Comment: Why not just make 10 threads, then? If you have 10 synchronous calls that need to be made in parallel then they need to be done in 10 threads. That's what synchronous means.

Comment: "then they see they need to wait, and directly look for more work." How would this happen? Are you literally calling wait?

Comment: @matt no iam currently not doing anything, this is part of my question, if you guys have an idea on how something like that could look like.

Comment: @kaya3 is it bad that the thread number is higher then the core count on my machine?

Comment: You can have more threads, especially if threads are not cpu bound. When they wait for some reason, eg calling wait, then the operating system has the chance to schedule other threads to run.

Comment: @matt so in the end, i just have a threadpool with 20 and the os is doing basically what i want anyway

Comment: Why not use an ExecutorService to do all this?  The Executors class will conveniently make you a service of the required kind.  Maybe Executots.newCachedThreadPool() is the one you want.

Comment: @user16632363 that is what iam doing, but i wondered if i can do it a little bit more resource efficient. But iam fine with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run a bunch of tasks on background threads and wait for them all to complete, then collect their returned results.

## Executors

The Executors framework was added to Java 5 to make this kind of work easy.

Define your task as a `Runnable` or `Callable`. In your case, a `Callable` because you want a value returned.

In our task, we simulate work that will take a long while by sleeping the current thread for three seconds. To simulate a result to be returned, we capture the current moment as an `Instant` object.

```java
Callable < Instant > task = () -> {
    Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 3 ).toMillis() );  // Simulating work that takes a long while. 
    return Instant.now();  // Simulating result of work to be returned.
};
```

Collect a bunch of tasks to be executed on background threads. Here we assign the same task object several time. You could alternatively instantiate multiple task objects.

```java
List < Callable < Instant > > tasks = new ArrayList <>();  // Collect tasks to be executed. 
int limit = 5;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++ ) { tasks.add( task ); }
```

Instantiate a [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) via [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) utility class.

You have a variety of executor service implementations to choose from with various behaviors. If you know you will have a small number of tasks to be run at a time, you may choose a cached thread pool which will generate a bunch of threads at a time. For a large number of tasks, choose another `ExecutorService` to avoid overwhelming your machine.

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

FYI… In the future, [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) may bring *virtual threads* ([fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science))) to Java to enable millions of simultaneous threads (if not CPU-bound). Experimental builds are available now, based on early-access Java 18. You would use [another executor service](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newVirtualThreadExecutor()):

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor();
```

If you have a large number of tasks, and are not yet using *Project Loom* technology, you may want to choose an [executor service backed by a limited number of threads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)).

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 );
```

Submit our collection of tasks to be executed. The result of each task submitted is a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). We track all the expected results as a collection of `Future` object.s

```java
List < Future < Instant > > futures = null;
try { futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Start the shutdown of our executor service. This prevents the submission of any more tasks.

```java
executorService.shutdown();
```

Wait for all the submitted tasks to complete. Assign a time-out to throw exception if the tasks are taking longer than expected.

```java
try { executorService.awaitTermination( 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Report results. Loop each `Future` object. See if the task was cancelled. If not cancelled, then we know it must have completed because we are past waiting for the executor service to shut down.

```java
for ( Future < Instant > future : futures )
{
    if ( future.isCancelled() )
    {
        System.out.println( "Canceled." );
    } else
    {
        try { System.out.println( future.get() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch ( ExecutionException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

When run, with a pair of `System.out.println` calls around our executor service’s executions. You can see all the tasks are submitted just ofter `21` second, they all sleep for 3 seconds, then all wake and execute at `24` second.

This run was on a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Apple Silicon M1, 2020) with 8 (4 performance and 4 efficiency) cores, using early-access Java 17.

```
INFO - Starting execution at 2021-08-28T21:33:21.514429Z
INFO - Ending execution at 2021-08-28T21:33:24.525798Z
2021-08-28T21:33:24.524563Z
2021-08-28T21:33:24.522178Z
2021-08-28T21:33:24.522177Z
2021-08-28T21:33:24.522178Z
2021-08-28T21:33:24.522181Z
```

## Scheduling of threads

[Your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68967757/make-thread-usable-if-it-waits-for-other-stuff/68968139?noredirect=1#comment121894142_68968139) is correct. A blocked thread in Java does *not* block use of a CPU core.

Current implementations of Java (at least through Java 17) use host OS threads as Java threads. This means the scheduling of which thread runs on which CPU core, and for how long, is controlled by the host OS.

Currently, if your Java code blocks, the Java thread blocks, and therefore the host OS thread blocks. Whether a thread, blocked or not, remains executing on the CPU core is up to the host OS.

Be aware that switching between host OS threads for execution on a CPU core is relatively “expensive”, costing CPU cycles for overhead, and possibly excessive memory assigned. This is why you should not overburden your machine with too many threads. Roughly the same number of threads as cores is a general guideline, though it varies depending on the nature of your tasks being executed.

### “Cheaper” threads in Project Loom

As mentioned above, virtual threads in *Project Loom* promise to make blocking Java code amongst Java threads much “cheaper”, meaning less memory and less CPU overhead.

A blocked virtual thread in Loom technology will much more quickly and easily switch the CPU core to work on another virtual thread. These virtual threads map to “real” host platform OS thread, many-to-one. These efficiencies mean that even millions of simultaneous threads may be reasonable on conventional hardware.

I am deliberately over-simplifying here. For full details on current threading technology and Project Loom’s changes, see recent presentations and interviews with Ron Pressler and other members of Project Loom.

You said:

> i thought that if i assign 5 threads to my threadpool, then i block 5 cpu cores.

As discussed above, a blocked Java thread does not block the CPU core. The host OS may choose to run other threads on that core at any time, whether your Java thread is blocked or not. By “other threads” I mean Java threads or threads of other apps. So keep in mind the bigger picture:  Your Java thread may be paused, at any moment, for any length of time, as the host OS sees fit given current operating conditions on that machine.

However, within Java, if you use an executor service backed by a fixed-size thread pool of five threads, with pending tasks submitted but not yet started, and all five current tasks happen to block, then no more work is performed by that executor service until the current blocking clears.

This is what changes under Project Loom with virtual threads: Any blocked *virtual* thread is set aside (“parked”) by the JVM (not the host OS), so that its host OS thread can immediately start executing one of the many other virtual threads sharing that “real” OS thread.

Comment: Your timeout idea is broken. [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) returns when the tasks are completed.

Comment: @matt I stand corrected, thank you. I do not actually use `invokeAll` in my own work, and hadn't noticed that fact. I'll update the Answer.

Comment: I think matt explane How to execute thread through Excutors.But, Maybe that Writer is hoping is executed during wait.For example, If in that situation some thread invoke someMethod after it is waited 3 second. But Writer needs to executed in waiting time.

Comment: thanks for the indepth explanation, but this is already what iam doing. I just thought ThreadCount = "blocked Cpu cores", so i thought that if i assign 5 threads to my threadpool, then i block 5 cpu cores. What i wanted yesterday is to "reuse" the waiting cpu cores, but this is not how this works and the OS is already doing that. So the actually solution is to put the threadcount to 20 and it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are waiting for is Project Loom:

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main

[http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rpressler/loom/loom/sol1_part1.html](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Erpressler/loom/loom/sol1_part1.html)

https://inside.java/tag/loom

This is coming to the JDK soon and is available in EA (Early Access) builds now for testing and feedback.